# devtools::build and devtools::check bottleneck - Cannot bundle package

Tags: r, devtools, r-package

Hopefully someone can help me understand the process which is causing this bottleneck.

I'm building an R package using packrat (I don't believe packrat is the issue, but I've only run into this problem since installing it).

When I try to build the source package, I get this far. I do have rtools installed and `devtools::find_rtools` returns `TRUE`. I have the same problem when I use `devtools::check`.

```
==> devtools::build()

"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.0/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save  \
  --no-restore --quiet CMD build "C:\my\working\directory"  \
  --no-resave-data --no-manual 

* checking for file 'C:\my\working\directory/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
```

Then it stops anywhere from 15-20 minutes before continuing with:

```
Warning in file.copy(pkgname, Tdir, recursive = TRUE) :
  problem copying .\my_pkg\.Rproj.user\B8520658\sdb\s-10B6532E\lock_file to
  C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp6jzytz\Rbuild2edc10811bab\my_pkg
ERROR
copying to build directory failed
```

My .Rbuildignore file looks like this:

```
^.*\.Rproj$
^\.Rproj\.user$
^README\.Rmd$
^README-.*\.png$
^data-raw/.*$
^notes$
^plots$
^\.Rprofile$
^packrat/
```

Since I've specified .Rproj.user in this file, why am I getting this error?

Is `devtools::build` copying my whole package directory? There are a few hundred MB of data in the directory, so that could explain some of the issue.

I've looked at the [devtools source code](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/blob/319706899dad8e851bbe22a1612604d2a9acd5ef/R/build.r) and don't understand what process is causing the issue.

Here's my session info:

```
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
```

I appreciate any help you have to give!

Comment: I'd recommend narrowing down the problem by starting with a fresh (empty) package, and then progressively copying in the contents of the existing package until you hit the problem.

Comment: This worked! I'll report back if I can figure out what I did to break it in the first place.